# Lazy Static initialization by compiler. in c++

Tags: c++, static, initialization, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to implement a small Test Factory with a registrar and tester class implementation, that register themselves with factory on program start (have taken code out of actual implementation, so might not compile; also, please ignore thread issues for getInstance in TestFactory, have removed that code to simplify.).

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual int test() = 0;
        virtual int createTestMsg() = 0 ;
};


typedef Base* (*pfn)();
class TestFactory {
    public:
        Base *getTester(int type) {
            auto iter = mTesterRegistry.find(type);
            if (mTesterRegistry.end() != iter) {
                return iter->second();
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        TestFactory * getInstance() {
           static TestFactory* ptr = new TestFactory();
           mInstance.reset(ptr);
           return ptr;
        }
    private:
        static std::map<int, pfn> mTesterRegistry;
        static std::unique_ptr<TestFactory> mInstance;
};

class Registrar {
    public:
        Registrar(MessageTypes type, pfnGetTester creator) {
            TestFactory::getInstance()->registerType(type, creator);
        }
};


// this is the test class implementation
class ToTest : public Base {
    private:
        static Registrar & registerMe();
        static Registrar & mRegistrar;
};


// test class cpp file.
Registrar &ToTest::mRegistrar = ToTest::registerMe();

Registrar & ToTest::registerMe() {
    static Registrar registrar(int, 
            []() -> Base * {return new ToTest();} );
    return registrar;
}
```

The problem is that in this method of initialization, the compiler does not create mRegistrar object till the time the compilation unit is loaded in memory (first called).
Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why is it a problem?  I mean you can't use the registrations until the file defining them is loaded anyway, right?

Comment: I want to initialize these static variables on program start, so, that means that I have to make a call to these test objects, before they are registered with the factory, that is not right solution.

Comment: Maybe you can make a sort of dummy method to call at the top of main() which will be implemented in the same .cpp file and force initialization earlier?

Comment: That is not feasible as this is going to be a library, probably used in other projects.

Comment: Well yours would not be the first library with a global init function.  I'd avoid it if you can, but if you can't, at least you're in good company.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I am trying to do just that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any dependable way that I know of.  The language is defined such that dynamic initialization of static scope objects can happen any time before the first use.  Only zero and constant initialization is guaranteed to happen before main.  I think it C++14 the rules are changed slightly such that constexpr functions and constructors are included in that.

I ran into a pretty nasty initialization race condition recently (VS2010, static initializers not thread safe) and I ended up having to go with this atomic double-check lock method to initialize the variable.  In fact it was such an annoying little hard to reproduce and find bug that I lost my job over it--I don't even know if my final attempt worked and probably never will.  If you find a way to guarantee dynamic initialization at some known point short of making sure to call any of these things in main (or perhaps DllMain or whatever) before spinning threads I would certainly like to know as well.  Short of that I'm going with a rule to never use static variables in pre-11 MT environment unless I'm suicidal or something.